# Como Criar uma Tabela N:N Onde Uma Das Chaves Não Pertence a Uma Tabela do Mesmo Banco de Dados

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relacionamento

**Contexto:**

A aplicação possui um módulo para registro de atendimentos e nós utilizamos uma outra aplicação lidar com o registro de incidentes, ambas estão em banco de dados diferentes.

Cada atendimento pode ser relacionado a um ou mais incidentes e um incidente pode estar relacionado a um ou mais atendimentos.
Estou utilizando `EntityFramework` em uma aplicação `ASP. Net MVC`.

**Solicitação**

Preciso associar estes atendimentos aos incidentes, não vejo uma forma de fazer isso por serem de banco de dados diferentes.

Pensei em realizar algo desse tipo, porém não tenho certeza sobre ser uma boa solução:

```
[Table("AssociacaoAtendimentoIncidente")]
public class AssociacaoAtendimentoIncidente
{
    public int AtendimentoId { get; set; } //Pertence ao banco de dados atual.

    public int IncidenteId { get; set; } //Pertence a outro banco de dados.
}
```

Como criar uma tabela que represente essa relação`(n:n)` ?

Comment: Você tem os contextos dos dois bancos mapeados na sua solução?

Comment: Não tenho, pois pertencem a soluções diferentes.

Comment: Então eu não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer, dessa forma AtendimentoId e IncidenteId são apenas atributos sem nenhuma realação de integridade.

Comment: Eles tem relação, mas não no nível da aplicação, mas sim no nível do negócio.

Answer (score 0):

Como você não tem um lado do seu modelo você vai ter que trata como 1/N, e mapear o ID da outra tabela. Não vejo outra forma de se fazer isso, a não ser que você tenha o modelo por completo.

```
[Table("AssociacaoAtendimentoIncidente")]
public class AssociacaoAtendimentoIncidente
{
    // FK
    public int AssociacaoAtendimentoIncidenteId { get; set; }
    // PK
    public int AtendimentoId { get; set; }
    // PK
    public int IncidenteId { get; set; } 
}
```

Na hora de persistir seus dados informe a PK da sua tabela pertencente ao outro banco.